# C / STM32 - Read and copy a data from .wav file

Tags: c, audio, stm32, wav

I am trying to copy a .wav file from my flash RAM memory.

```
#define AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE          (1024 * 8)       /* Size (in bytes) of the buffer containing the PCM samples */

uint8_t                  Buffer[AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE];    // Buffer containig the PCM samples to play
```

...

```
      /* Fill in the buffer with new data */
  if (f_read(&File, (uint8_t   *)Buffer, AUDIO_BUFFER_SIZE, &bytesRead) != FR_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  if (counter==1){
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      //uint8_t string[20]="Hello, world!";
      //f_write(&OutFile, Buffer, (UINT)sizeof(Buffer),&bytesRead);
      for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(Buffer); i++){
          f_printf(&OutFile, "%d\n",Buffer[i]);
          osDelay(10);
      }
      counter++;
  }
  else{
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LED_RED_GPIO_Port, LED_RED_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      f_close(&OutFile);
  }
```

When i do this, I get a file with some values like that (right part of this screenshot)
[Output file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z35r7.png)

How can i get the correct values as we can see them on the left part of my screenshot ?

Regards

Comment: By the way, `for(int i = 0; i <= sizeof(Buffer); i++)` looks like [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: Please write the numbers as text. Don't add pictures when you do not need to.

Comment: Oh yes, I change that like it : for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(Buffer); i++)

Comment: Aside: the data buffer contains `bytesRead` bytes. The `sizeof(Buffer)` is the **maximum** bytes that can be read, and the number of bytes actually read is `bytesRead`.

Comment: The desired output is floating point but you are reading/writing integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the values, your samples looks like being encoded in signed 16-bit little endian format.

To decode the format, you can do like this (assuming that the format specifier of `f_printf` is just like the standard `printf`):

```
// 2 bytes per sample, also use < instead of <=
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(Buffer); i += 2){
    int value = Buffer[i] | (Buffer[i + 1] << 8); // merge the 2 bytes into one integer
    if (value >= 0x8000) value -= 0x10000; // because the samples are signed
    f_printf(&OutFile, "%.4f\n", value / (double)0x8000); // divide with the maximum value
    osDelay(10);
}
```

If you cannot print floating-point number via `f_printf`, you can print with rounding by doing:

1. Multiply `10000` because there are 4 digits after the decimal point
2. Multiply 2 and add or subtract `0x8000` (the value used for division) based of the sign of the value
3. Divide by `0x8000 * 2`
4. Print the value before and after the decimal point

```
// 2 bytes per sample, also use < instead of <=
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(Buffer); i += 2){
    int v;
    int value = Buffer[i] | (Buffer[i + 1] << 8); // merge the 2 bytes into one integer
    if (value >= 0x8000) value -= 0x10000; // because the samples are signed
    // divide with the maximum value
    v = ((value * 10000) * 2 + (value >= 0 ? 0x8000 : -0x8000)) / (0x8000 * 2);
    f_printf(&OutFile, "%s%d.%04d\n",
      v < 0 && v / 10000 == 0 ? "-" : "", // sign (because typical integers don't have -0)
      v / 10000, // value before the decimal point
      (v < 0 ? -v : v) % 10000); // value after the decimal point
    osDelay(10);
}
```

Comment: Getting a file full of "%.4f" not data ... I'll try to see the value on debugging mode

Comment: Seems to be greater with a "value" defined as a "double" :D

Comment: f_printf lacks floating point support :( But the value is the good one

Comment: @Antoine Updated to add workaround of `%.4f`.

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much